# Split a string and combine 2 strings - C

Tags: c, string, gcc

I am trying to do a split of a string and then insert another string into the 1st string at the point of split.

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char src1[4]= "foo";
    char src2[4]= "bar";

}
```

I would like to split the `src1` as `f` and `oo` to insert `src2`, so that I get a single string `fbaroo`. What is the best way to do it in C?

I tried using `snprintf`, but I am not able to achieve the same. Following is the code:

```
snprintf(result, 1,"%s",src1[0]);
snprintf(result, strlen(src2), "%s",src2);
snprintf(result, strlen(src1)-1, "%s", **how do i get remaining characters**);
```

Ofcourse, I can have it initially split to combine later, but I am trying to find if there is a better solution i.e. using library functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snprintf`s in your code all all overwriting the buffer from the start.

Here's one way to do it with one call

```
snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%c%s%s", src1[0], src2, &src1[1]);
```

The `&src1[1]` shows how to get "the rest of the string."

Answer (score 1):

First you need a new string with enought space:

```
char finalString[7];
```

Then you need to copy the X first chars from `src1` to our new string, you can achieve this by [memcpy](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memcpy/), or [stcpy](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcpy/), I'll go with the later. So if you only want to copy the first character from `src1`you should do:

```
strcpy(finalString, src1, 1);
```

now just copy the `src2` string onto it using [strcat](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcat/)

```
strcat(finalString, src2);
```

and append the rest of the `src1` string, starting in the first uncopied char:

```
strcat(finalString, &src1[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `sprintf()`:

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char src1[4] = "foo";
    char src2[4] = "bar";
    char result[8] = {'\0'};

    sprintf(result, "%c%s%s", src1[0], src2, &src1[1]);
    printf("Result: [%s];\n", result);

}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Result: [fbaroo];
```